# Virtual Environment for Linux

Tags: linux, package-manager

I am looking for a program that can keep a history of the files and folder created by a certain package (x), so that when I delete that x package, it also deletes all the files that the package may have left behind.

It would compare to Python's virtualenv, exactly that.

Is there such program for a Linux OS (Debian)?

Comment: It's not exactly what you're looking for, but snaps and flatpaks work a bit like that - isolating the software from the system.

Comment: About the first part: gathering information you can use `audit` subsystem in Linux